# How to run JavaScript test script in multiple environments (terminal and browser)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have some tests that require jQuery. Well, we don't have to make believe, I actually have the tests. The test themselves are not important, but the fact they depend on jQuery *is* important.

> **Disclaimer:** this is node.js so you *cannot* depend on global variables in your solution. Any dependency must be called into the file with `require`.

**On the server** we need this API (to mock the window object required by server-side jquery)

```
// somefile.js
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
var window = jsdom().parentWindow();
var $ = require("jquery")(window);

// my tests that depend on $
// ...
```

**On the client** we need a slightly different API

```
// somefile.js

// jsdom is not required obviously
// window is not needed because we don't have to pass it to jquery explicitly
// assume `require` is available

// requiring jquery is different
var $ = require("jquery");

// my tests that depend on $
// ...
```

---

**This is a huge problem !**

The setup for each environment is different, but duplicating each test just to change setup is completely stupid.

I feel like I'm overlooking something simple.

---

**How can I write a single test file that requires `jQuery` and run it in multiple environments?**

1. in the terminal via `npm test`
2. in the browser

---

**Additional information**

These informations shouldn't be necessary to solve the fundamental problem here; a general solution is acceptable. However, the tools I'm using might have components that make it easier to solve this.

- I'm using `mocha` for my tests
- I'm using `webpack`
- I'm not married to `jsdom`, if there's something better, let's use it !
- I haven't used `phantomjs`, but if it makes my life easier, let's do it !

---

**Additional thoughts:**

- Is this jQuery's fault for not adhering to an actual [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)? Why would there be different APIs available based on which env required it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) to run my unit tests from the command line directly (CI too, with [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)).

Karma uses [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to run the tests inside of a headless browser, you can configure it to run in real browsers too.

Example of karma configuration inside of gulp:

```
// Run karma tests
gulp.task("unit", function (done) {
    var parseConfig = require("karma/lib/config").parseConfig,
        server      = karma.server,
        karmaConfig = path.resolve("karma.conf.js"),
        config      = parseConfig(karmaConfig, { 
            singleRun: true,
            client: {
                specRegexp: ".spec.js$"
            }
        });

    server.start(config, done);
});
```

In case of my tests it takes approx. 10 seconds to run 750 tests, so it's quite fast.